# Turf.js pointsWithinPolygon - creating a usable array

Tags: leaflet, buffer, turfjs

I've read through the docu on Turf.js pointsWithinPolygon and understand that it requires an array. I know what I want to accomplish but I'm not sure how to properly transform my L.geoJSON layers to satisfy the array condition. Please excuse the strange formatting as I've been playing around a lot lately and have lost some structure.

My points are:

```
    var employees2 = L.geoJSON();    
        
    Papa.parse('src/data1/Employees.csv', {
                        header: true,
                        download: true,
                        dynamicTyping: true,
                        skipEmptyLines: true,
                        complete: function(results) {
                            results.data.forEach((employee) => {
                                feature = {
                                    "type": "Feature",
                                    "geometry": {
                                      "type": "Point",
                                      "coordinates": [employee.Long, employee.Lat]
                                    },
                                    "properties": {
                                      "Postal Code": employee.Pcode
                                    }
                                  }
                                
                                       mrkEmployees = L.geoJSON(feature, {
                                           pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
                                               return L.marker(latlng, {icon: redcircle});
                                           }
                                           
                                       }).addTo(employees2)
                                mrkEmployees.bindPopup(employee.Pcode)
                            })
                        }
    });
```

and my polygons (which are turf buffers) are:

```
        var buffers2 = L.geoJSON();
       
        // parse local CSV file
        
        Papa.parse('src/data1/Houses.csv', {
                        header: true,
                        download: true,
                        dynamicTyping: true,
                        skipEmptyLines: true,
                        complete: function(results) {
                            results.data.forEach((house) => {
                                feature = {
                                    "type": "Feature",
                                    "geometry": {
                                      "type": "Point",
                                      "coordinates": [house.Longitude, house.Latitude]
                                    },
                                    "properties": {
                                      "Location": house.Location,
                                      "Type": house.Type
                                    }
                                  }
                                
                                       mrkHouses = L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(houses)
                                        houseBuffer = turf.buffer(mrkHouses.toGeoJSON(), 5, {units: 'kilometers'});
                                        lyrTest = L.geoJSON(houseBuffer, {style: 
                                                house.Type === 'Duplex' ? { color: "blue" } : 
                                                house.Type === 'Quadplex' ? { color: "yellow" } :
                                                { color: "red"}}).addTo(buffers2)
                                
                                        mrkHouses.bindPopup(house.Location);
                                        lyrTest.bindPopup("5km Buffer");
                                

                            })
                    }
            });
```

The part that is confusing me is how to pull out my array as many of my properties are defined within my parsed CSV code block and is therefore producing errors when trying to call coordinates.

Learning as I go. Afterward successfully defining the pointsWithinPolygon, I am going to attempt to export (save externally) said points as a layer - in case context helps.

Thanks as always - this community is very generous and extremely helpful.

EDIT - See [DEMO](https://filebin.net/bs1yds9h0ie7s6c8/index_-_Dec13_-_Example.html?t=yryjfe26) file.

[image]

Comment: in the house loading function you say that you want to load a polygon but you create `point` feature, this will not working. can you please share your data and how results looks like

Comment: I tried creating a jfiddle but there are too many plugins and data being parsed. I can include the main section of my js code though.

Comment: @FalkeDesign - I've updated the bottom of the post to include a link to the script and a screenshot of what it looks like. The parsed CSVs are simply lat/long + an identifier column. Just trying to figure out how to define an array from these to feed into Turf.js to create a list of points that fall within each buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the feature to a GeoJSON-Group, to add the group again to a GeoJSON-Group. One time is enough.

```
var employeesData = L.geoJSON(null,{
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: redcircle});
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties["Postal Code"])
    }
}).addTo(map);
...
...Papa loop
results.data.forEach((employee) => {
            var feature = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [employee.Long, employee.Lat]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Postal Code": employee.Pcode
                }
            };
            employeesData.addData(feature);
        })
```

Same for the buffer (I splitted the data and the buffers into seperate groups):

```
var housesData = L.geoJSON(null,{
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Location)
    }
}).addTo(map);

var buffersData = L.geoJSON(null,{
    style: function (feature) {
        return feature.properties.Type === 'Duplex' ? { color: "blue" } : feature.properties.Type === 'Quadplex' ? { color: "yellow" } : { color: "red"}
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("5km Buffer")
    }
}).addTo(map);

... Papa loop
            housesData.addData(feature);
            buffersData.addData(turf.buffer(feature, 5, {units: 'kilometers'}));
```

And then you can check if the points in the buffers:
(I don't know if the the first function is working, if not you have to check for each buffer if the points is in it `getPointsInPolygonForEachBuffer`)

```
var pointsInBuffer;
function getPointsInPolygon(){
    var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(employeesData.toGeoJSON(), buffersData.toGeoJSON());
    pointsInBuffer = L.geoJSON(ptsWithin).addTo(map);
}

function getPointsInPolygonForEachBuffer(){
    pointsInBuffer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
    buffersData.eachLayer((layer)=>{
        var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(employeesData.toGeoJSON(), layer.toGeoJSON());
        pointsInBuffer.addData(ptsWithin);
    })
}
```

Complete code:

```js
var employeesData = L.geoJSON(null,{
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: redcircle});
},
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties["Postal Code"])
}
}).addTo(map);

var housesData = L.geoJSON(null,{
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Location)
}
}).addTo(map);

var buffersData = L.geoJSON(null,{
style: function (feature) {
    return feature.properties.Type === 'Duplex' ? { color: "blue" } : feature.properties.Type === 'Quadplex' ? { color: "yellow" } : { color: "red"}
},
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("5km Buffer")
}
}).addTo(map);


Papa.parse('src/data1/Employees.csv', {
header: true,
download: true,
dynamicTyping: true,
skipEmptyLines: true,
complete: function(results) {
    results.data.forEach((employee) => {
        var feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [employee.Long, employee.Lat]
            },
            "properties": {
                "Postal Code": employee.Pcode
            }
        };
        employeesData.addData(feature);
    })
}
});


// parse local CSV file
Papa.parse('src/data1/Houses.csv', {
header: true,
download: true,
dynamicTyping: true,
skipEmptyLines: true,
complete: function(results) {
    results.data.forEach((house) => {
        var feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [house.Longitude, house.Latitude]
            },
            "properties": {
                "Location": house.Location,
                "Type": house.Type
            }
        };
        housesData.addData(feature);
        buffersData.addData(turf.buffer(feature, 5, {units: 'kilometers'}));
    })
}
});


var pointsInBuffer;
function getPointsInPolygon(){
var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(employeesData.toGeoJSON(), buffersData.toGeoJSON());
pointsInBuffer = L.geoJSON(ptsWithin).addTo(map);
}

function getPointsInPolygonForEachBuffer(){
pointsInBuffer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
buffersData.eachLayer((layer)=>{
    var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(employeesData.toGeoJSON(), layer.toGeoJSON());
    pointsInBuffer.addData(ptsWithin);
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, @falke-design. I re-arranged the code exactly as you laid out and everything is much clearer when separated into sections. Unfortunately, I don't think the pointsInPolygon functions are working. I tried console.log to see if these variables were filled with any data but kept coming back undefined. I also tried applying a different style to 'pointsInBuffer' to see if they showed up but didnt work and no errors.

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/n2q18y6o/) look in the demo, it works exactly how I described it

Comment: I didn't originally see the button portion of your code. This worked like a charm. thank you again,